# How to Fill the data in google spreadsheet after creation of sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have a script that create's an empty google spreadsheet.
after creation of google spreadsheet. how i can add some data in it?

just some string is enough

script for creating the file :

```
function createSpread() 
{

                var name =   $('[name=id]').val();
                gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {

                var request = gapi.client.request({
                   'path': '/drive/v2/files/',
                   'method': 'POST',
                   'headers': {
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
                   },
                   'body':{
                       "title" : name,
                       "mimeType" : "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
                       "parents": [{
                            "kind": "drive#file",
                            "id": FOLDER_ID,
                        }],
                   } 
                });
                request.execute(function(resp) { console.log(resp)

                });     
            }); 
}
```

Can you please help anyone

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an additonal tip for you, here's a code snippet I use when I'm writing to a spreadsheet using Sheets API.

```
 function writeToSheet(){

        //Sheet1 is the name of the my sheet
        // "range":"Sheet1!"+A+":"+C, means column A to C since im writing 3 items
         var params = {
           "range":"Sheet1!"+A+":"+C,
           "majorDimension": "ROWS",
           "values": [
           ["name","address", "email"]
          ],
         }
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open('PUT', 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+myspreadsheetId+'/'+"values/"+"Sheet1!"+A+":"+C+"?"+'valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED');
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + myAccessToken);

        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
      }
```

More samples are found in [Basic Writing](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing).

Comment: 1 more question : I have now a tabel And i want it to import to values . the problem is the table can contain 20 rows of values or 100 how can i make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Google Sheets API, which allows you to read and write to individual cells or cell ranges. See https://developers.google.com/sheets/api

Also, if this is a new application, you should probably start using v3 of the Drive API to save having to upgrade at some point.

Comment: Do you have an example with full javascripot because writting in the file shows only php and python

Comment: Follow the samples here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/  The API is a standard HTTP/REST/JSON API, so provided you know how to make http calls from JavaScript, you're all set